# What is an LLVM virtual section in the context of object files?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, object-files

Whilst looking at a [bugfix](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/9816f9eac902b84ec044bc11f6243d9e9400f3ef) in the LLVM source code, I came across the term, "virtual section" and wondered what it meant.

I tried Googling a few different terms and browsing the source code further, but all I managed to find was that the implementations for each object file format's `isSectionVirtual` member function appear to express that a section is virtual if it has no contents (such as a .bss section, but the source code clearly expresses that these are two different concepts). The implementation varies depending on the specific object format involved.

I am fairly new to understanding the innards of object files, so I am not sure if this is an LLVM thing or a more general concept present outside of LLVM.

Could somebody please tell me what a virtual section is in an object file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comments in LLVM source code, the "virtual section" is a section which doesn't have any data in object file. (PE/COFF specification doesn't have such term, so it's probably used only in LLVM).

The `.bss` section has only uninitialized data, so it shouldn't have any data in object file (although theoretically it can). So the `.bss` section should be "virtual", and there is no need to have the following code in LLVM:

```
if (Sec.isBSS() || Sec.isVirtual())
```

But the thing is that LLVM doesn't support "virtual" sections in Mach-O files (or maybe Mach-O files cannot have them)

```
bool MachOObjectFile::isSectionVirtual(DataRefImpl Sec) const {
  // FIXME: Unimplemented.
  return false;
}
```

Hence LLVM has separate checks for `isBSS` and `isVirtual`.

A BSS section is:

- readable
- writeable
- non-executable
- uninitialised data

A virtual section might have different properties and use cases, such as  writeable + executable, or non-readable (alignment) sections which are not BSS (note that writeable + executable sections are insecure, and "alignment" sections are useful only for some code protection (anti-dump) tricks).

So every BSS section is a virtual section, but not every virtual section is a BSS section.

Comment: Surely the separate checks indicate that these are in fact different concepts? Otherwise, there'd just be `isBSS` and `isVirtual` wouldn't need to exist. Thanks for your input regardless!

Comment: Thanks, that's much better!